# ¿ELIMINAR datos de una tabla, que no se encuentren en OTRA TABLA?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

básicamente mi pregunta es esa. Estoy utilizando **mysql**

En la **TABLA A**, tengo el campo **id_tablaB**.
Lo que quiero es hacer un **DELETE** en la **TABLA A**, solo de los registros que en el campo **id_tablaB** tengan un valor que **NO EXISTE** en la **TABLA B**

Comment: bueno.. es exactamente como lo estas diciendo.. como lo intentaste?

Comment: Una ayuda a lo que te dice @gbianchi: Un LEFT JOIN y un WHERE por los campos que no existen (nulos) de la otra tabla

Comment: @JLPrieto ni siquiera.. alcanza con un not exist.. como lo dice.. no existen ;)

Comment: @gbianchi cruzar las dos tablas y preguntar por los que no están en la otra. ¿o no?

Comment: Nop.. delete from A where A.id not exist in(la otra tabla)... @JLPrieto